# Restrict new language features of Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently working on a Visual Basic project with a team of developers, some of which will be able to move to Visual Studio 2015 as soon as it is released, and some who will be stuck on Visual Studio 2013 for several months.  In testing with the RC we have found that Visual Studio will open 2013 projects without a problem, but will happily let users use new language features, such as string interpolation, that are not available for users in VS 2013.  If a 2015 user checks in this code the 2013 users will get compile errors.  Is there any project, solution, or Visual Studio setting that will tell the compiler to restrict features to what is available in the previous version of VB.net?  Ideally the compiler should return a compile error when trying to use these features in 2015.

This features is available in C# under Project Properties > Build > Language Version, but I can't find any equivalent for VB.net, and the google searches are failing me.

I just wanted to mention that setting the .Net runtime version to 4.5 doesn't help, as these new language features are compiler level features that work perfectly fine on older frameworks.

Comment: This is sort-of duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2884368/736079

Comment: I'll give this a shot, hopefully it still works with the Roslyn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no UI feature to set the Language version, but you can unload the project file and add `<LangVersion>11</LangVersion>` to default Visual Basic to the 2012/2013 language settings. The C# project adds this property under the Project Configuration property groups, so for consistency's sake I've done the same in the sample below.

The C# property pages do the same thing, except that C# uses a different set of version numbers.

A full set of all the language versions can be [found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET).

```
2002 (VB 7.0)
2003 (VB 7.1)
2005 (VB 8.0)
2008 (VB 9.0)
2010 (VB 10.0)
2012 (VB 11.0)
2015 (VB 14)
```

Just tested and this works for me, but I did have to change the casing to:

[image]

This results in:

[image]

And a nice build failure:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, unless I added it to the wrong section of the project file.  Everything, including string interpolation is still compiling with this option set.

Comment: Visual studio is actually complaining about the element in the project file.  I've tried adding it as a child of `<Project>` and wrapped inside of a `<PropertyGroup>`.

Comment: Got it!  It's actually case sensitive (`<LangVersion>11</LangVersion>`) and needs to be wrapped in a `<PropertyGroup>`

Comment: Well, I may have spoken too soon. The project file is happy with it, but String Interpolation is still compiling, even with LangVersion set to 11.  If I set it to 9, it blocks it, but turns off other features as well.

Comment: Help > About lists it as "Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 RC Version 14.0.22823.1 D14REL"

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at a test project I created to make sure I'm doing it right? Thanks for your help. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42fIyGTLNv3el93R3YzbVREeG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Verified in actual release version of Visual Studio 2015.  Thank you!

Comment: Anybody know how to fix the opposite problem? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RTM and the VB 14 features aren't working. C# 6 does, but VB 14 seems to be nonexistent.

Comment: @rich new project or an existing one? If it's an existing one check the project file in notepad to see if a langversion is set, it should be 14 for the new features.

Comment: it's not - I tried adding it, but VS complains that it's an invalid element.

Comment: Can you post a new question and share that part of the project file?