# VB 14 missing from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015, but can't get the new VB language features to work. Or to show up. It's like the product came without it.  The null-coalescing operator doesn't work, read-only auto-properties aren't allowed, etc.  This is true even when I set up a brand new project, targeting any version of the framework (which shouldn't matter, but I'm trying everything I can think of).

I've got Resharper 9 installed.  Following a suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32122660/659019), if I select the project, the VB Language Level dropdown list doesn't show anything more recent than "Visual Basic .NET 12".

There are no LangVersion tags anywhere in the .vbproj files. If I add them it seems to make no difference.

I was under the impression that you didn't have to install anything separately for VB 14, just use VS 2015 and you'll have it (C# 6 actually is available and working in C# projects) but it's not there.

Anybody have any ideas what else I can look for?

Comment: Silly question - are you _sure_ it's VS 2015?  What does Help -> About say?

Comment: Presumably you do have .net 4.6 installed?

Comment: Help --> About says Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015, as one would expect.  Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL.

I do have .NET 4.6 installed.  It installed as part of the VS 2015 install, I assume, but it's definitely there and I can target projects to it.

Comment: Existing projects or new ones? Can yo share the first propertygroup section of your .vbproj in the question? What .NET framework are you targeting in your project?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454902/restrict-new-language-features-of-visual-basic-in-visual-studio-2015/31455783#comment52680789_31455783

Comment: Which framework is your project targeting?

Comment: Any version up to 4.6. When I noticed the problem I was working on 4.5.1, but a new project targeting 4.6 does it too.

Answer (score 5):

It's Resharper.

I'm using Resharper 9.2 Ultimate.  Resharper is what's putting all the error messages into the code editor.  If I suspend it, all the problems go away, and the code compiles and runs exactly as it should.

I should have taken a cue from the fact that the VB Language Level isn't showing the latest version of VB.

Off to contact technical support.

Comment: Here's the issue in their backlog about supporting VB14: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-442744

Comment: Looks like they have fixed this with the update to version 10.